# Sync load balanced AWS Lightsail with multiple instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, rsync, amazon-lightsail

I am planning to load balance AWS Lightsail with multiple instances.

Is it possible to auto sync files in main instance to another sub instances?

I would like to make easier to update themes and plugins when handling multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Lightsail has a shared drive, anything like AWS EFS. You have a few options though

- Map the drive of one instance across the network, using NFS or similar
- Use [S3FS](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) and S3 as a shared drive (note there will be additional latency)
- Sync files using something like rsync. I'm not sure this is a great idea, but if you only use it for things like images you might get away with it.

I'd probably go for letting Wordpress on each instance update its own files, and having media like attachments across NFS.